# Laravel 5.2 Form update error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Okay so guys i've a problem when working with laravel's update & i've spent 3 days and no one can solve my problem too so i decide to ask you all pro coder, please kindly help me

First, this is part of my View (editkeluhan.blade.php)

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/editkeluhanadmin/{$keluhan->id}') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                    <div>
                        <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
                    </div>
```

Second, This is my Route

```
Route::get('editkeluhan/{id}','AdminController@editkeluhan');
Route::post('editkeluhanadmin/{id}', 'AdminController@updatekeluhanadmin');

public function editkeluhan($id){
    $halaman="tindaklayanan";
    $keluhan=keluhan::findOrFail($id);
    return view('layanankonsumen.editkeluhan',compact('keluhan','halaman'));
}


public function updatekeluhanadmin(Keluhan $keluhan, Request $r){
    $halaman = 'tindaklayanan';
    $keluhan->update($r->all());
    return redirect('/');
```

Third, this is AdminController

```
public function editkeluhan($id){
    $halaman="tindaklayanan";
    $keluhan=keluhan::findOrFail($id);
    return view('layanankonsumen.editkeluhan',compact('keluhan','halaman'));
}

public function updatekeluhanadmin(Keluhan $keluhan, Request $r){
    $halaman = 'tindaklayanan';
    $keluhan->update($r->all());
    return redirect('/');
}
```

This is ERROR, but when i change my Route into this

```
Route::resource('editkeluhanadmin', 'AdminController@updatekeluhanadmin');
```

Error is gone BUT Its not update in database

Please Please Help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/update-form-data-laravel-52 to see my disscussion there & the answer if anyone need, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You use `PATCH` action in your form

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
```

so you need to change your route to:

```
Route::patch('editkeluhanadmin/{id}', 'AdminController@updatekeluhanadmin');
```

Comment: yup i've try both brother.. now its not error but still not change the value in database

Comment: print your `$r->all()` pls

Comment: btw idk what is $r is brother cause i got this from another person should i change $r with $keluhan ?